# How can i show the categories description?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on a wordpress site and im using this theme: [Ermark Adora](http://themeforest.net/item/ermark-adora-wordpress/152713)

I want to be able to add a description to my categories. Here's the code on the functions file where the code would go. [Here's the entire functions page (towards the end of the page)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7q42z71lf61plwf/functions.txt).

```
<li class="categ">
<h3> - '.$categ->name.' - </h3>';
if ($products_full=='true') {
$src['full_categ'] .= '<a href="#" class="less-products">'.__('view all','adora').'</a>';
$src['full_categ'] .= '</li>'
```

What code do I need to add in oder to display the category's description?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)?

Comment: I tried 'category_description( $category_id );' but I dont know exactly how to write it in order for it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer: `<h3> - '.$categ->name.' -</h3><p> '.$categ->description.' </p>';`

Answer (score 0):

Please Google before asking such a questions. The answer is in the WP codex:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/category_description

`echo category_description( $category_id );`

Comment: I did try that code but the description still doesn't show up.